# How to run and control a commandline program from python?

Tags: python, csv, cmd

I have a python script which will give an output file. I need to feed this output file to a command line program. Is there any way I could call the commandline program and control it to process the file in python?

I tried to run this code

```
import os
import subprocess
import sys

proc = subprocess.Popen(["program.exe"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
proc.communicate(input=sys.argv[1]) #here the filename should be entered
proc.communicate(input=sys.argv[2]) #choice 1
proc.communicate(input=sys.argv[3]) #choice 2
```

is there any way I could enter the input coming from the commandline. And also though the cmd program opens the interface flickers after i run the code.

Thanks.

Note: platform is windows

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html. It's the current way to go when starting external programms. There are many examples and you have to check yourself which one fits your needs best.

Comment: >>> import shlex, subprocess
>>> command_line = raw_input()
/bin/vikings -input eggs.txt -output "spam spam.txt" -cmd "echo '$MONEY'"
>>> args = shlex.split(command_line)
>>> print args
['/bin/vikings', '-input', 'eggs.txt', '-output', 'spam spam.txt', '-cmd', "echo '$MONEY'"]
>>> p = subprocess.Popen(args) # Success! ------- will this be applicable if i use windows ... im not sort of familiar with the codes above though from what i use in windows

Answer (score 0):

You could do [`os.system(somestr)`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.system) which lets you execute `semestr` as a command on the command line. However, this has been scrutinized over time for being insecure, etc (will post a link as soon as I find it).

As a result, it has been conventionally replaced with [`subprocess.popen`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

depending on how much control you need, you might find it easier to use [pexpect](http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/pexpect.html) which makes parsing the output of the program rather easy and can also easily be used to talk to the programs stdin. Check out the website, they have some nice examples.

Answer (score 0):

If your target program is expecting the input on `STDIN`, you can redirect using [pipe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28Unix%29):

```
python myfile.py | someprogram
```

Answer (score 0):

As I just answered [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12891724/subprocess-using-several-command-line-tools) regarding subprocess, there is a better alternative!

Please have a look at the great library [python sh](http://amoffat.github.com/sh/), it is a full-fledged subprocess interface for Python that allows you to call any program as if it were a function, and more important, it's pleasingly pythonic.

Answer (score 0):

Beside redirecting data stream with pipes, you can also process a command line such as:

```
mycode.py -o outputfile inputfilename.txt
```

You must import sys

```
import sys
```

and in you main function:

```
ii=1
infile=None
outfile=None
# let's process the command line
while ii < len(sys.argv):
arg = sys.argv[ii]
        if arg == '-o':
            ii = ii +1
            outfile = sys.argv[ii]
else:
            infile=arg  
        ii = ii +1
```

Of course, you can add some file checking, etc...