# Subprocess - using several command line tools

Tags: python, command-line, subprocess, pipe, os.system

I'm a learning newbie to python and to working in the command line, e.g. piping.

I've read that subprocess is encouraged way instead of os.system. I'm creating a script which invokes the shell and I have not been able to do it using subprocess. Using os.system was a snap though:

```
os.system("cut -f1-4 " + temp1.name + "| uniq --count | sort -rn > " + temp2.name)
```

I've used subprocess with success for other commands, but not those that combine more than one tools with "|". Reading the subprocess python documentation was confusing and not helpful to me. I've also tried searching other questions but could not find something similar to my problem. This is what I've tried (and failed):

```
subprocess.call = (["cut", "-f1-4", temp1.name, "|",  "uniq", "--count", "|", "sort". "-rn"], stdout = open(temp2.name, 'w'))
```

I've also tried substituting sp.call with sp.Popen, but failed. Can anyone please help with some clear examples and explanation? 
Thanks!

Comment: `subprocess.call = (…` – You’ve just replaced a library function with a tuple. Why do you expect that to work? You need to call the function…

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. Can you please explain futher? I've used subprocess.call successfully by calling the items in a list, e.g. subprocess.call(["program", inputfile, outputfile])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use pipes you should add `shell=True`

```
subprocess.check_output("cut -f1-4 " + temp1.name + "| uniq --count | sort -rn > " +    temp2.name, shell=True)
```

Please note that if `temp1.name` or `temp2.name` come from an untrusted source (e.g. from data supplied by a user in a web application) using `shell=True` is be a security risk.

Comment: Thanks @hans! That worked!! But I'm unclear why use sp.check_output since I want to read the output and not just check if the command works? This is confusing. Anyway there is minimal security risk since the temp1.name and temp2.name files are generated by the script based on specific user input.

Comment: Sorry to add to the confusion. You can simply use `call` if you only want to check the return value. It was force of habit made me type `check_output`.

Comment: Hm, I swear I tried that before and it didn't work with sp.call. And that's why I broke the whole line into a list because that's what sp.call accepts (based on what I understand). Anyway thanks again!

Comment: Maybe you did not specify `shell=True` the first time?

Comment: I tried too many thigns to remember. I think I tried that but I broke the command into list items (e.g. in question) as I read that sp.call takes item in lists and that's how I've been using sp.call. Then I added shell=True but it did not work. But thanks again, something new I learned today. :)

Answer (score 2):

It's worth taking a look at the great library [python sh](http://amoffat.github.com/sh/), it is a full-fledged subprocess interface for Python that allows you to call any program as if it were a function, and more important, it's pleasingly pythonic.

For your specific need in this case, it provides some 'advanced piping' feature, sth like this:

```
# the inner command executes first, then sends its data to the outer command
from sh import *
sort(uniq(cut("-f1-4", _in="temp1.name"), "--count"), "-rn", _out="temp2.name")
```